# Question about Ann's refusal to believe Chris in What Dreams May Come

Tags: what-dreams-may-come

How is Ann's refusal to believe in Chris's afterlife existence affecting her and her family? How is she affecting the belief of her children?

Comment: Welcome to [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour). I am at the moment unable to judge this (since I haven't seen the movie for a long time and don't know what you're actually referring to right now), but *if* those two questions are rather unrelated to each other, it is preferable to ask them each as individual questions.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I'm in the same boat but if my memory is correct, these questions are pretty unrelated. I recommended splitting them into more than one the first time she asked (and there was a third question about suicide that didn't seem to relate to the film I thought seemed off topic). The question was deleted and reposted with just these two questions but still not split up.

Comment: I guess I'm not going to get an answer. They ARE related to the film. Try watching it again

Comment: @Maya It isn't about if they are related to the film, I won't deny that, but if they are related to *each other*. We are not trying to dissect your questions or arguing that they are bad or off-topic. We are actually trying to help you getting good answers to them by improving them. And for this it might be better to ask both questions each as separate questions. This site works by asking one question after the other, putting multiple questions into a single one when they are not related might be counterproductive for finding a conclusive answer to them.

Comment: @Maya Thanks for splitting up the questions!  Remember, we're just other users, too and unless someone's recently seen the film and/or has put a lot of thought into this topic, it may take a while to get a response. These are good questions but they're really deep, so it can take some time! Keep checking back regularly!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this question. I haven't seen the film in a while, but didn't the children die at the very start? Once Chris died, what family does she have left to affect?

Comment: This sounds like a test essay question from college. Way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way. People involved shape each other. They define happiness, togetherness, loneliness, identity for each other at least in that they contain and reflect each other. (A more accessible example is the daughter's choice to take the shape of kindness: an Asian girl, in her father's representation.) And it's normative; as mirrors, they are the (only valid) means by which one judges oneself. And it's reciprocal; denying their existence not only equals (living) hell but keeps *them* incomplete and (their) heaven indeterminate. It affects them the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to answer this but I'll take a stab at it since this is one of my favorite movies and I've seen it several times.

**How is Ann's refusal to believe in Chris's afterlife existence affecting her and her family?**
Well its affect on her is that she is stuck in Hell in an old house and in her mind she is living a dark reality (she doesn't know she is dead) and she will never again be reunited with her family.

So the affect on her family is of course sadness because they love her and want to be with her. They are also affected in that Chris decides to go after her and he is accompanied by (unknown until later) their son Ian who appears as Chris' colleague. Had Ian followed Chris into Hell to rescue Ann there would have been other possible consequences such as Ian become lost too.

**How is she affecting the belief of her children?**

Their belief in what exactly? In Chris' afterlife? I'm not sure she was affecting that at all. They both had already created their own worlds and Chris was in the process of creating his own. Had she remained in Hell I doubt they would have stopped believing in something they had first hand knowledge of.

If you're talking about their faith, I supposed the affect was that they were able to see how their parent's were truly soul mates which according to Ian is very rare, and how Chris was able to tap into that to bring Ann out of her depression and return with him to his afterlife.

Hopefully this provides some kind of answer. If not, you may want to be more specific in what exactly it is you are asking.